# Cant Get D3 To Even Print Text

Tags: d3.js

This is driving me nuts.  Iv followed tutorials and I cant get this thing to do the simplest of actions.

Im just trying to get started. Iv got a skeleton page, a bare bones JSON file and the D3 V3 library loaded.

I can see from the inspector that everything loads fine. The JSON loads fine, but nothing happes. Im just trying to print some words into a few li elements, but i get nothing.  I can see that the ul is appended to the page, but nothing else.

There's no JS errors, or anything to guide me.  Just a blank page.

What am I doing wrong here?!

My Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>    
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/vendor/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <style>

        path {
          stroke: #fff;
          fill-rule: evenodd;
        }

        </style>
        <script>
        function draw(data){
          "use strict";
          d3.select("body")
          .append("ul") 
          .selectAll("li") 
          .data(data) 
          .enter() 
          .append("li")
          .text(function(d) {
            return 'Cant even see this message'; 
          });
        }
        </script> 
      <script>d3.json("json/status.json", draw);</script>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
    </html>
```

and my JSON file

```
{
  "status": "OK",
  "name": "TEST A"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `var data` is not in correct format. D3.js assumes you will pass list to it but you provide an object. One simple fix to get you started would be to change status.json to:

```
[{
  "status": "OK",
  "name": "TEST A"
}]
```

From the API docs: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-data

> selection.data([values[, key]])
>
> Joins the specified array of data with the current selection. The
>   specified values is an array of data values, such as an array of
>   numbers or objects, or a function that returns an array of values.

Comment: Man, something so simple. I couldnt find that mentioned anywhere ..  Yes, that's got me up and running now.. Thanks for your help